# PyInstaller not working Python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

I made a program with Tkinter, CV2, Numpy, winsound, as well as others. I made it into an EXE with PyInstaller, but when I open it it says something like "Fatal Error -1".

This is the command prompt message:

```
40277 INFO: checking EXE
40308 INFO: Building because out00-EXE.toc is bad
40308 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
40542 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\WINDOWS\system32\dist\app.exe
```

When I open the app.exe file it says "Fatal Error! app returned -1"
I think the problem might be in the PIL because it works without it.
Here is the source code that produces the same problem:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
import cv2
import csv
```

When I ran the code without

```
from PIL import ImageTk
```

it worked fine.
Please Help!

Comment: copy here the exact error if you want some help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my own answer. I had to import another  module before importing ImageTk

```
import FileDialog
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
```